# How to restart the containers if app hangs or crash in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using docker-compose to run my application but not able to find a solution for this:

- How to restart the container if the container hangs or the application crashes. In Kubernetes we have readiness. What do we have in docker-compose?
- Is there a way to send alerts if the above condition happens.

Comment: You can use `restart` policy in your `docker-compose` file. https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/. Did you try that?

Comment: Yes. But it's for app crash. What if app becomes not responsive or hangs?

Comment: I think your application should handle this, and this is not what docker can do

Comment: This feature is one of the reasons Kubernetes exists (Liveness, Readyness, Destroy the pod etc). In Docker Compose - you will have to come up with something of your own.